# python permission denied writing output to file

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, apache2, python

I want to execute a python file in `/var/www/html`:

```
sudo python myFile.py
```

Which works fine.

Now, I want to write the output to `log.txt`.

So, I type:

```
sudo python myFile.py >> log.txt
```

However, I get the following error:

> -bash: log.txt: Permission denied

Though I changed the permissions of log.txt:

```
sudo chmod u+x log.txt
```

And `ls -l log.txt` returns:

> -rwxr--r-- 1 www-data www-data 0 Feb  3 16:04 log.txt

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you running `myFile.py` with www-data?

Comment: Could it be that /var/www/html is on a network share? Try `df /var/www/html`

Comment: Try `sudo bash -c "python myFile.py >> log.txt"`

Comment: @bc2946088 Yes, I am www-data

Answer (score 2):

The problem here `sudo python myFile.py >> log.txt` is that you run `sudo python myFile.py` as root, but your shell is still running as your regular user, which means `>>` redirection won't work if you don't have permission to write to the `log.txt`

As George properly noted, you should do `sudo bash -c "python myFile.py >> log.txt"`. Alternatively, if your `myFile.py` doesn't require root privileges, you can do `python myFile.py | sudo tee log.txt`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I assumed already such a situation, that the shell has not the rights. However, is there a possibility to change the rights to log.txt so that I can do it without sudo? I tried it (see above), but I assume that the rights were just changed for my user (group) and not for the bash, right?

Comment: @black The file is owned by `www-data` user and group. So, you could add yourself to `www-data` using `sudo usermod -a -G www-data <USERNAME>`  command (where `<USERNAME>` is your actual username). Although I wouldn't recommend doing that. As far as I understand , `www-data` group is for your web server, so if your account gets compromised, attacker could have access to modifying the web server without need for `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

Two options I can think of:

1. `sudo bash -c "python myFile.py >> log.txt"`, or
2. `sudo chmod u+x myFile.py`, then `sudo ./myFile.py >> log.txt`